# Multiple variable loop in scala

Tags: java, scala

I wants to iterate two variable in loop and populate the map.Java code looks like below.

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < header.size(); i++, j++)
{
  map.put(header.get(i), cols.get(j));
}
```

How can we achieve this in Scala? Please can anyone help on this?
Help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need two variables here? Variables `i` and `j` always have the same value, haven't they? So why don't use `i` instead of `j`? If your real code is more complicated - show us some better example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Scala**, you can use `zip` to do this, like:

```
header.zip(cols).toMap
```

Comment: When i added this line of code in programmer it  doesn't iterates more than a single record.

Comment: @user1734980, I think you can paste a runnable code for this. if your `header` or `cols` not **Scala** **Collection**, maybe you need to convert it to **Scala** collection.

Answer (score 1):

One way is `map` over your **headers** along with the index of each entry and get the `col` for the same index and create a map.

Given,

```
scala> val headers = Seq("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4")
headers: Seq[String] = List(h1, h2, h3, h4)

scala> val cols = Seq("c1", "c2", "c3")
cols: Seq[String] = List(c1, c2, c3)
```

`map` on `headers` *`cols.lift(i)` is safe way when `headers.size > cols.size`*

```
scala> headers.zipWithIndex.map{case (h, i) => h -> cols.lift(i).getOrElse("")}.toMap
res50: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(h1 -> c1, h2 -> c2, h3 -> c3, h4 -> "")
```

If `headers.size == cols.size` or if you don't want header which does not have equvalent col, you can use `list.zip(anotherList)`,

```
scala> headers.zip(cols)
res52: Seq[(String, String)] = List((h1,c1), (h2,c2), (h3,c3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest

```
val map = (0 until header.size) map { n => header.get(n) -> header.col(n) } toMap
```

As a fairly naive translation.

This assumes that `header` is just an arbitrary object with a few `def`s, not a proper collection.